# Modify DATE in WP_Query

Tags: wordpress, date

It is possible to change the order by date in WP_Query?

I mean, something like this:

```
  'orderby' => date('d m')
```

Answer (score 0):

OrderBy takes a string or an array as parameters

On the wordpress codex, there are examples that could help you in your needs.

```
$week = date( 'W' );
$year = date( 'Y' );
$query = new WP_Query( 'year=' . $year . '&w=' . $week );
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#date-parameters